# Fragment within ViewPager not showing immediately

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a main fragment with a viewpager inside it. This viewpager has 2 pages (fragments). Everything works fine.

When I start the activty, the main fragment is shown and I also want to show (ie. load data) of the first paged fragment.

Currently I have:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) pagerAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, position);
    if (fragment instanceof IPagedFragment) {
        ((IPagedFragment) fragment).onShown();
    }
}
```

This is the pager adapter:

```
private static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public PagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:  return Frag1.newInstance();
            case 1:  return Frag2.newInstance();
            default: return null;
        }
    }

   //Other overrides...
}
```

However, calling `setCurrentItem` does not call `onPageSelected`.

How can I force the first fragment to call its `onShown` method?

Comment: Why `instantiateItem()` and not `getItem(position)`? Show us your adapter code please.

Comment: @shkschneider adapter code added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the ViewPager does not call `onPageSelected` for the first item.

Also `setCurrentItem` will not trigger `onPageSelected` cause the current Page of the ViewPager has not actually changed. (The initial page is 0)
Take a closer look in the [source code](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-support-v4/blob/master/src/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java) (`setCurrentItemInternal`) if you want to know how it works.

A solution is to call `onPageSelected(0)` directly instead of `setCurrentItem`.